# In the Play Route's file, how can indicate to use routes from a module?

Tags: scala, module, compiler-errors, routes, playframework-2.0

Currently trying to follow Manning's Play for Scala, specifically the section on testing a module before publishing.

I've created a module named "Ean2BarcodePlayModule" with organization "net.nowhereatall.playforscala".

I've used activator to publish local to ~/.ivy2/local

In my test project, I've added the library dependency:

```
"net.nowhereatall.playforscala" %% "ean2barcodeplaymodule" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Now, I'd like to modify my routes file to indicate

```
->      /barcode                    Ean2BarcodePlayModule.Routes
```

but this results in:

```
 [error] D:\Tutorials\Workspaces\Scala\Ean2BarcodePlayModule-Test\conf\routes:10:
 not found: value Ean2BarcodePlayModule
[error] ->      /barcode                    Ean2BarcodePlayModule.Routes
[error] D:\Tutorials\Workspaces\Scala\Ean2BarcodePlayModule-Test\conf\routes: no
t found: value Ean2BarcodePlayModule
[error] D:\Tutorials\Workspaces\Scala\Ean2BarcodePlayModule-Test\conf\routes: va
lue setPrefix is not a member of Any
[error] D:\Tutorials\Workspaces\Scala\Ean2BarcodePlayModule-Test\conf\routes:10:
 not found: value Ean2BarcodePlayModule
[error] ->      /barcode                    Ean2BarcodePlayModule.Routes
[error] four errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed Mar 12, 2015 1:36:34 PM
```

alternatively, if I try:

Now, I'd like to modify my routes file to indicate

```
->      /barcode                    net.nowhereatall.playforscala.Ean2BarcodePlayModule.Routes
```

the result is:

```
[error] D:\Tutorials\Workspaces\Scala\Ean2BarcodePlayModule-Test\conf\routes:10:
 object nowhereatall is not a member of package net
[error] ->      /barcode                    net.nowhereatall.playforscala.Ean2Ba
rcodePlayModule.Routes
[error] D:\Tutorials\Workspaces\Scala\Ean2BarcodePlayModule-Test\conf\routes: ob
ject nowhereatall is not a member of package net
[error] D:\Tutorials\Workspaces\Scala\Ean2BarcodePlayModule-Test\conf\routes: va
lue setPrefix is not a member of Any
[error] D:\Tutorials\Workspaces\Scala\Ean2BarcodePlayModule-Test\conf\routes:10:
 object nowhereatall is not a member of package net
[error] ->      /barcode                    net.nowhereatall.playforscala.Ean2Ba
rcodePlayModule.Routes
[error] four errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 6 s, completed Mar 12, 2015 1:35:56 PM
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I don't think that there is a simple way of using another modules Route file. To be able to split routes in multiple sub-projects ( modules ), your sub-projects need to be built specificaly to be used as sub-projects inside a Play project as explained here - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SBTSubProjects . Though it is definitely possible to achieve this, but it will take a lot of `sbt` wizardry.

Comment: At least at the time Manning's book was written, it seems there _was_ a way, but then he was speaking of modules instead of subprojects.  Have subprojects replaced modules?  I can't seem to find any real discussion of modules with regards to Play 2.3.

Comment: Well... I don't think the word `module` has or ever had any real meaning in `Scala` or `Java`. It's just that people understand that a `module` is kind of a `piece` which can be combined with other `pieces` to create a bigger `piece`. And hence some people use word `module` for `projects` which are specifically built to be used as `pieces` for some bigger piece.

Comment: For a meaningless word, "module" seems to have been thrown around a lot... but anyway, after reading the page on subprojects a few more times, I found that by renaming routes in the module to "barcode.routes" I was then able to access it in the test project as "barcode.Routes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to @Sarvesh Kumar Singh for directing me to the page on "SubProjects", the solution was relatively simple.

1. Rename "routes" in the the module source to "barcode.routes".
2. Redo activator publish-local.
3. In the "Test" project route file, include the required line as

   ->      /barcode                    barcode.Routes

(Note the last "R" in "Routes" is capital.  That seems to be important!)